# How to properly test a thunk that called another thunk with mock-store

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

A simplified version of my thunks:

```
fetchUserThunk = () => async (dispatch) => {
dispatch(requestUserStart());
const payload = await getUserAPIrequest();
dispatch(requestUserSuccess(payload));
dispatch(fetchHobbies(payload.userId));
```

};

```
fetchHobbiesThunk = (userId) => async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(requestUserHobbiesStart());
    const payload = await getUserHobbiesAPIrequest(userId);
    dispatch(requestUserHobbiesSuccess(payload));
};
```

I have the following test:

```
it('test', async () => {
    const store = mockStore({});
    store.dispatch(fetchUserThunk());

    const expectedActions = [
        requestUserStart(),
        requestUserSuccess(userObj),
        fetchHobbiesThunk(userObj.id)
    ];
    expect(store.getActions()).to.deep.equal(expectedActions);
});
```

It fails because the third action is `requestUserHobbiesStart`.
How do I properly test this thunk?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up refactoring to what was suggested here - https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/1676#issuecomment-215413478